# How to sort list by nested values

Tags: python

How to sort list by minimal nested [0],[1] and [2] values?

Input example:

```
[[-10.0, -10.0, 20.0], [30.0, -10.0, 20.0], [30.0, 20.0, 20.0], [-10.0, 20.0, 20.0]]
```

Output example:

```
[[-10.0, -10.0, 20.0], [-10.0, 20.0, 20.0], [30.0, -10.0, 20.0], [30.0, 20.0, 20.0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sorted built-in function for it.

```
l1= [[-10.0, -10.0, 20.0], [30.0, -10.0, 20.0], [30.0, 20.0, 20.0], [-10.0, 20.0, 20.0]]
sorted_l1 = sorted(l1)
print(sorted_l1)
```

Output:

```
[[-10.0, -10.0, 20.0], [-10.0, 20.0, 20.0], [30.0, -10.0, 20.0], [30.0, 20.0, 20.0]]
```

Answer (score -1):

Normally itself, **Sorting** happens by checking from the 1st element till the last element in the list.

Now if it is a nested list, the elements will be a *list* itself, thus it would again check from the 1st element till the last element.

Therefore `sorted(lst)` or `lst.sort()` will return your desired output only.